# How to use both JavaFX Scene Builder while still have the choice to design root with code?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, scene

I wanted to give SceneBuilder a try because its pain to center objects manually (in code). Unfortunately root is taken from me when I use FXML, so I can't set group as root. What I want to do is to operate on canvas (that is added to root group) while still having SceneBuilder FXML file working.

For example when Ive set root sceneBuilder FXML file then i couldnt add sprites to it in code. Vice versa when I have set root as group then the application wasnt making use of FXML file.

**How to connect these?** Below is code with use of group as root. I have added sprite, which is not visible in SceneBuilder. Also the button made in SceneBuilder is not visible after compiling the application.

Code:

```
package zegelardo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Zegelardo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));


        Group rootx = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootx);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Zegelardo");

        Sprite tlo = new Sprite();
        tlo.setImage("test55.gif");
        tlo.setPosition(0, 0);



        Canvas canvas = new Canvas( 800, 400 );

        rootx.getChildren().add(canvas);

           GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // gc.clearRect(0, 0, 1000,800);
               // briefcase.render( gc );

                tlo.render(gc);
       // Group leaf = new Group();
       // root.getChildren().add(canvas);
       // Canvas canvas = new Canvas( 800, 400 );
        //leaf.getChildren().add( canvas );

        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You never add the `root` to the Group `rootx`. Also the names must represent something meaningful. Finally you should make a Controller class for the FXMLDocument. You can make it extend the root cause which you want for example 'BorderPane' and do whatever you want inside the `initialize()` method of the controller class.

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Mate I dont know what you mean.

Comment: `rootx.getChildren().add(root)`?

Comment: @James_D thanks for response (again) but that doesn't solve my issue. Im either getting window with objects from code or fxml scene builder window (instead of having it together)

Comment: OK instead of Group use a BorderPane for testing. Add the root on the top of the BorderPane and the Canvas on the Center of the BorderPane. What happens?

Comment: OK instead of Group use a BorderPane for testing. Add the root on the top of the BorderPane and the Canvas on the Center of the BorderPane. What happens?